# .NET C# special character

Tags: c#, .net, character

I have a C# application in which I am trying to make a string that will contain near the end \0.
I didn't manage to do that.
I did:

```
string msg = "GGGG..8";  
byte []b = System.Text.encoding.GetBytes(msg);
```

but in b where ".." are the representation is 46 and not 00.
I want instead of `..` to have \0\0
The final goal was to have the string contain the message.

Comment: Your code won't compile, as "System.Text.encoding.GetBytes(msg)" isn't valid. *Which* encoding are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating an appropriate string is easy:

```
string msg = "GGGG\0\08";
```

It's not clear what encoding you were trying to use in the second line, but I'd expect *most* single-byte encodings to encode that '\0' as a 0 byte.

If you want to take a message which *originally* includes periods and convert them to '\0' characters, that's easy too:

```
string msg = "GGGG..8";
string replaced = msg.Replace('.', '\0');
```

Comment: Thanks, I am so bad in that issue of characters and converting and ascii. Do you know a good reference to understand that ?

Comment: It's not clear *exactly* what you're interested in. My article on strings *may* help: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx

Comment: Thnaks for the article, I ment when using unicode when converting ? when it is represneted in UTF7 or 8 etc ..

Comment: @RomanDorevich: What do you mean by "converting ?" exactly? It's tricky - you need to be more precise in your terminology before I can answer your questions accurately, but until you know your way around the subject a bit better, you can't be more precise in your terminology... hopefully my article will clear things up a bit more.

Comment: @jon i read your article  , but does `string s="1"` also stored as unicode 16 bits ? 8 bit is fine for this case.... you said it has a flag which can tell if the string contains non ascii charcter...well...thats not the case its ascii charcter. what size will it be in memory ? ( bytes)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
string msg = "GGGG..8\0";
```

If no luck try this:

```
string msg = "GGGG..8" + '\0';
```

Comment: Sorry, I wanted instead of .. \0\0

Comment: I think the "in the end" means "eventually" in this case, not "at the end of the string".

Comment: Yes, but i also wrote it to be duplcated \0 and made an example, but I will change it

Comment: Nice catch @Jon and as usual, your answer can't be bested. :-)